# Watson Assistant Font changing on csv downloads and uploads

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation

Foreign language symbols changing when downloaded as csv into excel?
They recover on upload to Watson.
New entries made in Excel get screwed up on upload.
Any solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant uses `UTF-8` encoding for import and export of the data. I am wondering if the problem might be that your local Excel assumes different default encoding causing the data to appear messed up (because they are in a different encoding then the Excel assumes).
You can check this by opening the csv file in some text editor that can set encoding to `UTF-8`.